# Visual Studio 2013.2 Performance Issues

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2013

Recently I've been having some major performance issues with my Visual Studio 2013.2 Ultimate. Doing anything in Visual Studio (editing a code file - each mouse click / key press has a delay of 1-2 seconds, navigating in Visual Studio menus - the who environment is very unresponsive)

I have tried a number of things to improve the performance - I have uninstalled the custom AddIns, I have tried switching on and off "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance". I have not quiet gone as far as doing a complete reinstall of Visual studio - and hoping I wouldn't have to go that way.

Is there any other way to debug the performance issues of Visual Studio? I have not had any issues with it in the past - but it is driving me absolutely insane.

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Investigating it a bit further - looks like it has something to do with the specific solution that I'm working with. Solution is a medium in size ASP.NET MVC and a number of class library projects (around 8 all up - with maybe 250 classes in total). The solution is under Visual Studio Online TFS source control

Comment: When in doubt uninstall Resharper if you have installed it and try again. Simply disabling will not shut it down completely.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation! I don't have resharper - but may try uninstalling all of the extensions rather than just disabling them.